# How to use ID JOIN instead of DATEDIFF()

Tags: sql

Write a SQL query to find all dates' id with a higher temperature compared to its previous dates (yesterday).
Try out if you want: https://leetcode.com/problems/rising-temperature/

```
   Input: 
Weather table:
+----+------------+-------------+
| id | recordDate | temperature |
+----+------------+-------------+
| 1  | 2015-01-01 | 10          |
| 2  | 2015-01-02 | 25          |
| 3  | 2015-01-03 | 20          |
| 4  | 2015-01-04 | 30          |
+----+------------+-------------+
Output: 
+----+
| id |
+----+
| 2  |
| 4  |
+----+
```

Here's my code:

```
SELECT w_2.id AS "Id"
FROM Weather w_1
JOIN Weather w_2
ON w_1.id + 1 = w_2.id
WHERE w_1.temperature < w_2.temperature
```

But my code won't be accepted even if it looks exactly like the expected output.
[image]

I know the answer is:

```
SELECT w2.id
FROM Weather w1, Weather w2
WHERE w2.temperature > w1.temperature
AND DATEDIFF(w2.recordDate, w1.recordDate) = 1
```

But I tried to not use DATEDIFF because this function is not available in PostgreSQL.

Comment: try doing AS "Id" or AS \`Id\` instead of just AS Id

Comment: Oh yeah when I tried double quotation marks it changed the case. but i still can't pass the test... do you have any idea why

Comment: it would appear as though the answer would boil down to the order of records in the submission table versus the test table - they switch things up in the test table to {"headers": {"Weather": ["id", "recordDate", "temperature"]}, "rows": {"Weather": [[1, "2000-12-16", 3], [2, "2000-12-15", -1]]}} where the record id's increase with decreasing dates, which would invalidate the order of operations you were using. it doesn't seem to care about ID vs Id vs id in actuality.

Comment: @procopypaster Where did you this test table?  If that were the test table, shouldn't the expected output be 1, instead of 2.

Comment: In leetcode, if you look at the tab in the upper left for "Submissions", it is in there. I am guessing they did it this way to force users to use a date function, since it's only assumed that id and record date move in the same direction.

Comment: @procopypaster I saw it. I guess you're right. I just assumed too much. Thanks dude

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The queries are not compatible. You should join the table on `recordDate`, not on `Id`.

```sql
SELECT w_2.id AS "Id"
FROM Weather w_1
JOIN Weather w_2
ON w_1.recordDate + 1 = w_2.recordDate
WHERE w_1.temperature < w_2.temperature
```

Do not assume that `Id` is sequential and ordered in the same way as `recordDate`, although the sample data may suggest this.

Comment: Yeah. Since it's said that ID is the primary key, I just assumed that IDs are continuous and unique. But I tried your code, it won't be accepted. :(

Comment: I'm sorry I deleted my previous comment. After reading the question again, I understand where you come from.

Comment: Well, now the queries follow the same logic. Perhaps some other considerations are involved, but I find it hard to guess. Anyway, our query is more modern and elegant than the original.

Comment: Haha. Can't agree more

Comment: I tried all the edge cases I can think of and decided this query is of no problem!